# How to use Lodash keyBy to get user ID -> title out of entire user object?

Tags: javascript, key, lodash

For instance, say I have a few user objects in an array:

```
[{name: "Bob", ID: "123", location: "Texas"},
 {name: "Jill", ID: "124", location: "New York"},
 {name: "Jan", ID: "125", location: "Alabama"}]
```

and I want to get just the IDs and put them in a new array with some other variable that will be retrieved elsewhere, but corresponding to that ID, such as:

```
[{ID: "123", title: "Engineer"},
 {ID: "124", title: "Architect"},
 {ID: "125", title: "Manager"}]
```

How can I achieve that with Lodash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the solution has to use lodash at all means, then ignore this one.
Otherwise...

This can be done with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var persons = [
  {name: "Bob", ID: "123", location: "Texas"},
  {name: "Jill", ID: "124", location: "New York"},
  {name: "Jan", ID: "125", location: "Alabama"}
];

var result = persons.map(function(person) {
  return {
    ID: person.ID,
    title: "" /* get title */
  };
});

console.log(result);
```